# How to get element in bootstrap popover after ajax has loaded

Tags: jquery, html

I use php foreach to get the list of elements to rate using ajax pagination, each element use bootstrap popover for rating (means the rating html is in 'data-content' attr). On first load everything work fine ,I can see other pages when I click on pagination link but when ajax has loaded the bootstrap popover doesn't show.

-How to get 'data-id' and 'data-name' attribut of 'rate-multi-select' class.
-How to get value of input.
-How to get ID attribut of 'multi-ajax-user-rating' class.

**Here is the popover rating:**

```js
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html:true}).click(function(e) {e.preventDefault();});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>test</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
<div class="title-multi-rating popovered-rating popovered" title="Rate this!?" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="<form method='POST' action='' class='orb-form orb-rating-form' id='orb-form'>
  <section>
    <label class='label'></label>
    <div class='rating rate-multi-select' id='rate-select' data-id='118' data-name='people'>
      <div class='multi-ajax-user-rating' id='0'></div>
      <input type='radio' name='stars-rating' value='100' id='stars-rating-100'>
      <label for='stars-rating-100' title='Juste magique :)'><i class='fa fa-heart'></i></label>
      <input type='radio' name='stars-rating' value='90' id='stars-rating-90' >
      <label for='stars-rating-90' title='Excellent'><i class='fa fa-heart'></i><label>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--<button type='submit' name='submit-rating' class='btn btn-success' value='ok'>Evaluer</button>-->
</form>">
<span><img class="rating-image" src="/assets/images/Icons/icon-hate-large.png" alt=""/><strong>Element1</strong></span>
</div>


    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I dont see any ajax calls

Answer (score 0):

If you only use JavaScript:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('rate-select'); 
    var attr_id = elem.getAttribute('data-id'); 
    var attr_name = elem.getAttribute('data-name');
    var elem_by_class = document.getElementsByClassName('multi-ajax-user-rating');
    
    console.log(attr_id);
    console.log(attr_name);
    console.log(elem_by_class);
    
    for (var i = 0, n = elem_by_class.length; i < n; ++i) {
    console.log( elem_by_class[i].id);  
}
```

```html
<div class="title-multi-rating popovered-rating popovered" title="Rate this!?" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="">
<form method='POST' action='' class='orb-form orb-rating-form' id='orb-form'>
  <section>
    <label class='label'></label>
    <div class='rating rate-multi-select' id='rate-select' data-id='118' data-name='people'>
      <div class='multi-ajax-user-rating' id='0'></div>
      <input type='radio' name='stars-rating' value='100' id='stars-rating-100'>
      <label for='stars-rating-100' title='Juste magique :)'><i class='fa fa-heart'></i></label>
      <input type='radio' name='stars-rating' value='90' id='stars-rating-90' >
      <label for='stars-rating-90' title='Excellent'><i class='fa fa-heart'></i></label>
    </div>
  </section>
  <!--<button type='submit' name='submit-rating' class='btn btn-success' value='ok'>Evaluer</button>-->
</form>
<span><img class="rating-image" src="/assets/images/Icons/icon-hate-large.png" alt=""/><strong>Element1</strong></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but I use bootstrap popover so why 'data-content' attr is empty

Comment: I think your HTML is broken, i edited it in my code snippet.  Can you please fix it in your code?

Comment: if you try to run your code snippet you will see that you have syntax errors

Comment: I added bootstrap but don't forget popover doesn't work after ajax has loaded

Comment: Well now I see u use jQuery, and my answer does not make sense any more. Anyways I you still have syntax errors in your code.

Comment: This way of programming is new to me, the way you add data-content and the form in it. Are you sure that it should work ?

Comment: yes works like a charm on first load but when I change page and after ajax has loaded it doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

There are some events of `ajax` to handle actions

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $( ".bootstrap-element" ).show();
});


$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  $( ".bootstrap-element" ).hide();
});
```

This 2 function will run everytime you will make an `ajax` call. I suppose `ajaxStop` will do the job.

For more information please check [this link](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)

Comment: You didn't get it....I said the bootstrap popover doesn't show when the ajax has loaded the elements